# PEG: What is wrong wrong with my grammar for if statement?

Tags: parsing, rust, grammar, peg

I'm implementing an OCaml-like language using [rust-peg](https://docs.rs/peg/0.6.3/peg/) and my parser has a bug.
I defined if-statement grammar, but it doesn't work.

I'm guessing the test-case input is parsed as `Apply(Apply(Apply(Apply(f, then), 2) else), 4)`. I mean `"then"` is parsed as Ident, not keyword.

I have no idea for fixing this apply-expression grammar. Do you have any ideas?

```rust
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
pub enum Expression {
    Number(i64),
    If {
        cond: Box<Expression>,
        conseq: Box<Expression>,
        alt: Box<Expression>,
    },
    Ident(String),
    Apply(Box<Expression>, Box<Expression>),
}

use peg::parser;
use toplevel::expression;
use Expression::*;

parser! {
pub grammar toplevel() for str {

    rule _() = [' ' | '\n']*

    pub rule expression() -> Expression
        = expr()

    rule expr() -> Expression
        = if_expr()
        / apply_expr()

    rule if_expr() -> Expression
        = "if" _ cond:expr() _ "then" _ conseq:expr() _ "else" _ alt:expr() {
            Expression::If {
                cond: Box::new(cond),
                conseq: Box::new(conseq),
                alt: Box::new(alt)
            }
        }

    rule apply_expr() -> Expression
        = e1:atom() _ e2:atom() { Apply(Box::new(e1), Box::new(e2)) }
        / atom()

    rule atom() -> Expression
        = number()
        / id:ident() { Ident(id) }

    rule number() -> Expression
        = n:$(['0'..='9']+) { Expression::Number(n.parse().unwrap()) }

    rule ident() -> String
        = id:$(['a'..='z' | 'A'..='Z']['a'..='z' | 'A'..='Z' | '0'..='9']*) { id.to_string() }
}}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(expression("1"), Ok(Number(1)));
    assert_eq!(
        expression("myFunc 10"),
        Ok(Apply(
            Box::new(Ident("myFunc".to_string())),
            Box::new(Number(10))
        ))
    );

    // failed
    assert_eq!(
        expression("if f then 2 else 3"),
        Ok(If {
            cond: Box::new(Ident("f".to_string())),
            conseq: Box::new(Number(2)),
            alt: Box::new(Number(3))
        })
    );
}
```

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Err(ParseError { location: LineCol { line: 1, column: 11, offset: 10 }, expected: ExpectedSet { expected: {"\"then\"", "\' \' | \'\\n\'"} } })`,
 right: `Ok(If { cond: Ident("f"), conseq: Number(2), alt: Number(3) })`', src/main.rs:64:5
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the peg library, but if it has a way to add predicates to rules, you could create a set of keywords and then add a predicate to the `ident` rule that requires the identifier to not be in the set of keywords. You'll also want a rule for keywords to make sure that something like `ifFunction thenArg elseArg` is parsed as a function call rather than as `if Function then Arg else Arg`.

Answer (score 2):

PEG uses ordered choice. This means that when you write `R = A / B` for some rule `R`, if in a position `A` succesfully parses, it will **never** try `B`, even if the choice of `A` leads to problems later on. This is the core difference with context-free grammars, and often overlooked.

In particular, when you write `apply = atom atom / atom`, if it's possible to parse two atoms in a row, it will **never** try to parse just a single one, even if it means the rest doesn't make sense later.

Combine this with the fact that `then` and `else` are perfectly good identifiers in your grammar, you get the issue that you see.